# DefaultHttpClient execute bring different location from browser

Tags: java

its seems i have a bug but i cant find any clue in google.
i have the following code:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    setupHTTPS(httpClient);
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    // set proxy data, if available
    if (proxyHost != null) {
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(proxyHost, proxyPort), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(proxyUsername, proxyPassword));
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
    }

    RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    httpClient.setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy);
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    // allow circle redirect with limiting the numbers of redirects
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.MAX_REDIRECTS, 50);

    // set userAgent , if available
    if(userAgent!=null){
        setUserAgentForHttpClient(userAgent,httpClient);
    }       

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, context);

    RedirectLocations locations = (RedirectLocations) context.getAttribute(DefaultRedirectStrategy.REDIRECT_LOCATIONS);
```

and i tried to run it on url: http://annemergmed.com/action/consumeSharedSessionAction?JSESSIONID=aaaiJSrshFbnYctW3Q4Rv&MAID=I1JsdfY3Lc%2FzCjqdBXuiSQ%3D%3D&SERVER=WZ6myaEXBLHj3ZzqSv9HPw%3D%3D&ORIGIN=378011271&RD=RD&acw=&utt=

but i got different location from what i see in firebug. totaly different! (i am runing firebug on privat browsing)
how can it be? what am i missing?

Comment: Your url contains JSESSIONID. Was that session (with that ID) still alive when you made your call via `HttpClient`?

Comment: i closed the connection. but its work for me in other sites like that.